# Get recent 6 months of records for a particular id

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get the most recent 6 months of records for a particular id(in my case client id) using the service date for that client.

Here is the snapshot of my table :

[image]

Output should be client_id, service_date(but only of recent 6 months).Please help me with the query as i am new to sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [INTERVAL function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#:%7E:text=Snowflake%20supports%20three%20variations%20of,The%20default%20precision%20is%209.) requires the period (in this case 6 MONTHS) to be in single quotes.

This worked for me:

```
SELECT 
      CLIENT_ID
    , SERVICE_DATE 
    , SERVICE_DATE::DATE-INTERVAL'6 MONTH' PRIOR_6_MONTHS_FROM_SERVICE 
    , CURRENT_DATE()-INTERVAL'6 MONTH'   PRIOR_6_MONTHS_FROM_TODAY
FROM 
    CTE 
WHERE
    SERVICE_DATE>PRIOR_6_MONTHS_FROM_TODAY
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

incase your table has the most recent service date which is quite old (older than 6 months) then you will first have to find the last recent date and then 6months data back from that last recent date

```
LAST_VALUE(SERVICE_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY CLIENT ID ORDER BY SERVICE DATE) as most_recent_date_per_client
```

This will give you most recent date per client id and then you can use the column from above and apply the Interval to go 6 months back

```
where client_id = xxxxx and service_date > most_recent_date_per_client - interval 6 month
```

otherwise, you can use the solutions from above which focus on the CURRENT_DATE()

```
WITH MOST_RECENT_CLIENT_DATE AS (
    select
    client_id,
    service_date,
    LAST_VALUE(service_date) OVER(PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY service_date) as most_recent_date_per_client
    
    FROM [TABLE NAME]

)

SELECT 
    client_id
    service_date
from 
    MOST_RECENT_CLIENT_DATE
where 
   client_id = xxxxx and service_date > most_recent_date_per_client - interval 6 month
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use:

```
select t.*
from t
where client_id = <whatever> and
      service_date > current_date - interval 6 month;
```

Comment: Yes, but i cant use the client_id filter as i need to store all the client id to a new table.
Recent 6 months of service date for a particular client should be grouped by a client id

Comment: @G4Gaurab . . . Your question is:  "Get recent 6 months of records for a particular id".  That is what this code does.